# How to get particular index for any data from list using Java Stream?

Tags: java, android, list, java-8, java-stream

Here is a code to check if particular string is matched or not from List

```
if (Stream.of(getPlayingSongList()).filter(o -> o.getId().equals(songList.get(position).getId())).findFirst().isPresent()) {
           ToastMethod.show(getActivity(), "Song is already in queue", true);
        }
```

I want to know, which index from `getPlayingSongList()` is matching.

I am using `com.annimon:stream` library in android.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about using [`IntStream.range`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#range-int-int-) ?

Since I don't have you whole code, I'm just putting a dummy example :

```
String[] myArray = { "a", "b", "c", "d" };
OptionalInt c = IntStream.range(0, myArray.length).filter(n -> "c".equals(myArray[n])).findFirst();

if (c.isPresent()) {
   System.out.println(c.getAsInt());
}

>>>> 2
```

Answer (score 2):

using Akah's suggestion, for android, below code works well.

```
Optional<Integer> c = Stream.range(0, getPlayingSongList().size()).filter(n -> songList.get(position).getId().equals(getPlayingSongList().get(n).getId())).findFirst();

            if (c.isPresent()) {
                Log.i("get index", c.get()+" ok");
            }
```

Thanks a lot.